# How to use the Json Variables in Azure DevOps YAML Pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-pipelines-tasks

I want to deploy the azure resources(ADF) and while deploying I need to override some DEV ARM template parameters and one of the parameters to deploy is of **JSON OBJECT** which I store its value in the **pipeline Variable Group** as below
[image]

Actually the value looks like this `{"minutes":[00],"hours":[5],"weekDays":["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday"]}`

Since in azure DevOps pipeline, **every Variable value** that we fetch will be treated as a **string type** but my parameter for the ARM template need the value of **Json type**.

```
 - task: AzurePowerShell@5
      displayName: Deploy ADF
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
        ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
        Inline: 

          New-AzResourceGroupDeployment `
             -ResourceGroupName "$(DeploymentResourceGroupName)" `
             -TemplateParameterFile "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$(SourceDataFactoryName)/ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json" `
             -TemplateFile "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$(SourceDataFactoryName)/ARMTemplateForFactory.json" `
             -factoryName "$(DeployDataFactoryName)" `
             -LocalTesting_properties_typeProperties_recurrence_schedule $Trigger_Schedue `
             #<parameter-overridden> : <value-to-be-overridden> there are parameters in arm template and overridden by key vault secrets `
             #<parameter-overridden> : <value-to-be-overridden> (add any other parameter overrides as needed) `
             -Mode "Incremental"
        azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
```

so whenever I try to run the pipeline it **fails**  because the parameter **LocalTesting_properties_typeProperties_recurrence_schedule** is expecting the **Json** data but here I provided the **string**.
I also tried the **ConvertFrom-Json** and "ConvertTo-Json" but not able to get the desired output.

Can you pls help me here?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `jq`.

You first parse it `$scheduleJson= jq --null-input '$(Trigger_Schedule)'` and then pass it as parameter.

```
 - task: AzurePowerShell@5
      displayName: Deploy ADF
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
        ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
        Inline: 
          $scheduleJson= jq --null-input '$(Trigger_Schedule)'
          New-AzResourceGroupDeployment `
             -ResourceGroupName "$(DeploymentResourceGroupName)" `
             -TemplateParameterFile "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$(SourceDataFactoryName)/ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json" `
             -TemplateFile "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$(SourceDataFactoryName)/ARMTemplateForFactory.json" `
             -factoryName "$(DeployDataFactoryName)" `
             -LocalTesting_properties_typeProperties_recurrence_schedule $scheduleJson`
             #<parameter-overridden> : <value-to-be-overridden> there are parameters in arm template and overridden by key vault secrets `
             #<parameter-overridden> : <value-to-be-overridden> (add any other parameter overrides as needed) `
             -Mode "Incremental"
        azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
```

Comment: @Kryzysztof this is not working for me at all

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: This isnot even working in the local PowerShell.
$jsonString = '{"minutes\":[55],"hours":[10]}'
jq --null-input '$(jsonString)'

jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting IDENT or __loc__ (Windows cmd shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
$(jsonString)
jq: 1 compile error

Comment: Try this `$jsonString = '{"minutes\":[55],"hours":[10]}' jq --null-input $jsonString`